# Syntax error help

Tags: php, dreamweaver, syntax-error

I seem to have a syntax error and can't see it myself, could someone run over it for me please?

Thanks.

```
<script>
    var acurl_<?php echo $request_data['friendship_id']; ?> = "sn-include/create_bond_accept.php?friendship_id=<?php echo $request_data['friendship_id']; ?>&friend_id=<?php echo $fromuser['id']; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: split the code on more lines and give us the line error

Comment: Do you have a syntax error in PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: anyway never heard of heredox syntax? eh Xd

Comment: It doesn't say in dreamweaver, it just states there is a syntax error on this line of code, and code hinting may not work. Maybe its a missing symbol or a wrong symbol somewhere. I looked through it and it looks fine, but a red error box in dreamweaver is a no no ;).

Comment: oh gosh. is it just dreamweaver or the  PHP parser ?

Comment: I would say Dreamweaver is a no no ;)

Comment: Id ignore any errors by dreamweaver and actually test the screen yourself in a browser.

Comment: Maybe just the DW javascript syntax checker doesn't like your PHP in javascript. Does it work anyway? :)

Comment: It works yeah. But It just annoys me that its telling me its wrong, but I leave it on just to make sure when I'm inputting code, things are in the right place. 
Cheers guys. :)

Comment: You guys are rough.  Dreamweaver sucks, but try to point the guy down the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David, on the bright side, you don't have a syntax error.

If you're developing PHP, I would recommend two things:

1. Get a better IDE.  Dreamweaver is TERRIBLE for working with PHP.  I recommend [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) (it's awesome and free).
2. Start breaking up your code into chunks.  The big ball of html and PHP is hard to debug.

Check this out:

```
<?php
    // prepare output
    $segment  = '?friendship_id=' . $request_data['friendship_id'];
    $segment .= '&friend_id=' . $fromuser['id'] . '";' . "\n";

    $acurl  = 'var acurl_' . $request_data['friendship_id'];
    $acurl .= ' = "sn-include/create_bond_accept.php';
    $acurl .= $segment;

    $dnurl  = 'var dnurl_' . $request_data['friendship_id'];
    $dnurl .= ' = "sn-include/create_bond_deny.php';
    $dnurl .= $segment;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
        echo $acurl;
        echo $dnurl;
    ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you got some answers that intended to show you how to improve your code, but actually don't do so (IMO), here is my attempt:

```
<?php 
    $acurl = array();
    $acurl[$request_data['friendship_id']] = sprintf('sn-include/create_bond_accept.php?friendship_id=%s&friend_id=%s', $request_data['friendship_id'], $fromuser['id']);
?>

<script>
    var acurl = <?php echo json_encode($acurl); ?>
</script>
```

I would not create dynamic variable names. This code would create a JS object, where the properties are the friendship IDs, something like:

```
{
    '42': 'sn-include/create_bond_accept...'
}
```

You can access these URLs more easily from JavaScript than if you have dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Use here doc instead:

```
<?php
echo <<<JS
<script>
    var acurl_{$request_data['friendship_id']} = "sn-include/create_bond_accept.php?friendship_id={$request_data['friendship_id']}&friend_id={$fromuser['id']}";
</script>

<script>
    var dnurl_{$request_data['friendship_id']} = "sn-include/create_bond_deny.php?friendship_id={$request_data['friendship_id']}&friend_id={$fromuser['id']}";
</script>
JS;
?>
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: heredoc might not be as bad as echoing strings, but in general it makes it harder to maintain the code, syntax highlighting does not work etc.

Comment: @Felix, hard to maintain as compared to what?, and syntax highlighting is dependant on your editor.

Comment: @Petah: As opposed to a properly structured MVC application. You should always do whatever you can to separate the HTML from the PHP, doing "<strong><?php echo $var; ?></strong>", for example, where $var is defined in a separate file or, at the very least, at the top of the file. Loops can be done like so: "<?php foreach ($foo as $bar): ?> ... <?php endforeach ?>". Syntax highlighting rarely shows for HTML within a PHP string - I've used plenty of IDEs and not seen that once.

Comment: @Muu, I fail to see what part of that code I am declaring variables, in other words, that code could be used in a view...

Comment: You're not, I just mentioned it for completeness. What you've written there is PHP, with HTML in it. It should be the other way round - HTML with PHP interspersed.